I can not add two fields in oracle apex form 20, displaying Wrong Date format
I'm working on an Oracle APEX application with three fields: P3_WSTART_DATE1 (a date input field), P3_WPERIOD (a number input field), and P3_WEXPIRY_DATE (a display-only date field). I have a dynamic action that calculates the expiry date based on the start date and the period in months.
Here's the SQL query I use to perform the calculation:
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(:P3_WSTART_DATE1, :P3_WPERIOD)
FROM DUAL
Problem:
When I input 10/11/2024 into P3_WSTART_DATE1 and 12 into P3_WPERIOD, I expect P3_WEXPIRY_DATE to show 10/11/2025.
Instead, it displays 10/11/2025, which appears to be HTML-encoded.
Steps Taken:
I set the Format Mask for P3_WEXPIRY_DATE to MM/DD/YYYY in the Page Designer.
I configured a dynamic action on the P3_WPERIOD field that updates the P3_WEXPIRY_DATE field based on the values of P3_WSTART_DATE1 and P3_WPERIOD.
I confirmed that the values entered in P3_WSTART_DATE1 and P3_WPERIOD are correct before the calculation.
Questions:
Why is the date displaying as HTML entities instead of the expected format?
Are there specific configurations I need to check in Oracle APEX to ensure the date format displays correctly?
Is there anything else I might be missing that could cause this issue?
Environment:
Oracle APEX version: 20.1.0.00.13
Database version: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
two add :P3_WSTART_DATE1 and :P3_WPERIOD and trying to show in field P3_WEXPIRY_DATE but result is wrong date format

What does "which appears to be HTML-encoded." mean ? Can you show a screenshot ? What is "a display-only date field" ?
I tried to reproduce (on apex 24.1 - I have no access to older versions)

Create page item of type Date Picker P275_DATE
Create page item of type Display Only P275_DATE_1
Create Dynamic Action on change of P275_DATE with the following true action:


Tested this and it works as expected:

What did you do different and what are you seeing ?
